# How can you customize object creation in django?

Tags: python, django

In django rest framework, it's possible to make a function to customize the process of creating an object inside the serializer of that respective model, but I can't figure out how to do that in "vanilla" django, so to speak. What I need to do is take one field and do a bunch of stuff with it. encode it into a 256 character hash is all I have to worry about now. How can I go about doing what I need? I've been basing myself off of an online course and Django's documentation, but I either couldn't interpret it well enough or I just straight up haven't found it there. Here is the code I have so far, at least what I judge is relevant to the question. It's all in models.py:

```
class SpedFile(models.Model):
json_file = models.FileField(max_length=100)
sped_file = models.FileField(max_length=100)
integrity_hash = models.CharField(max_length=256)
line_counter = models.CharField(max_length=150000)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

@classmethod
def create(cls, json_file):
    file_bearer = json_file
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(file_bearer.encode('utf-8'))
    integrity_hash = m.hexdigest()
    new_object = cls(json_file=file_bearer, integrity_hash=integrity_hash)
    return new_object
```

Comment: And what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Although the more normal thing to do would be to override `save` and put this logic there.

Comment: This code isn't listing anything, so I'm not even sure it's creating anything at all. could you specify what you mean by that?

Comment: I'm not sure what "isn't listing anything" means. How are you calling this code, what are you expecting to happen and how is it different from what you are actually seeing? As I said, you would normally do this when you save the model instance, not when you create it, which you would achieve by defining the save method.

Comment: It's a model in a django project. The model is called in a function based view and the form works as intended, but my list view doesn't bring anything back. I'm sure it's not a problem with listing itself, but creating the object the way I intend to. Could you write a reply to this showing what you mean by using the save method?

Comment: First you need to show your full code. **How are you calling the create method**? You suddenly mention a form here; where is it? If there's a form, then this logic probably belongs there anyway. Show the code of the form and the view that uses it.

Comment: My bad for the long time I took to get back to this, but now I understand what you meant by the save method. I'll ask a new question since I think the problem changed significantly by now.